# Not able to drop a column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am a beginner in data analysis with python, and I am currently stuck on why I keep getting a key error even after looking up multiple sources on how to fix it. Here is a small sample of my data
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1N4q.png)

I have tried running this code:
`SATdf.drop(['School ID'], axis=1, inplace= True) SATdf.drop(['Building Code'], axis=1, inplace = True)`
However I keep getting this error:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yd3j.png)
Same for building code.
I appreciate any pointers.

Comment: `SATdf.drop(columns=['Building Code'])`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, I just tried your suggestion, I'm still getting a key Error and 'School ID' not being found in the axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `SATdf.drop(columns=['School ID','Building Code'], inplace= True)` ?

Comment: Yes I just tried it, it's returning a key error again saying "['Building Code'] not found in axis".

Comment: Delete de axis argument. If you pass just the columns argument, it should select the axis automatically

Comment: I deleted the axis argument and I also copied your code to see if it worked, I'm getting the same error strangely.

Comment: Could you print in a separate line `SATdf.columns.values` and check that the name is spelled right and there are no white spaces at the beginning or end of the keyword?

Comment: Oh I tried rerunning it by deleting the axis argument again. It turns out it worked. I am so sorry for wasting your time for my dumb mistake...